# sort_by multiple attributes in hash

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, ruby-on-rails-6, geocoder

I want to be able to sort my posts based on

- created_at asc(and include distance)
- vote_count desc (and include distance)
- distance asc

So far I've been able to sort by distance, but I'm having trouble figuring out how to construct my map and still be able to keep `distance` visible to my users in the array (even though they have chosen to sort by `vote_count` for instance)

**User calls update_order from view**

```
def update_order
  @order = params[:order]
  @posts = Post.all
  get_distance_posts
end
```

**The method that determines the distance:**

```
def get_distance_posts
    posts = {}
    @posts.map{ |post| posts[post.id] = (check_coordinates_present?(post, current_user) ? get_users_distance(post,current_user) : 0 ) }
    @sorted_posts = Hash[*posts.sort_by {|_key, value| value}.flatten]
end
```

**My view.html.erb**

```
<% @sorted_posts.map do |u_id, dist|  %>
    <% post = @posts.find(u_id) %>
    <p> <%= post.created_at %> </p>
    <p> <%= post.vote_count %> </p>
    <p><%= dist %></p>
<% end%>
```

Any help would be greatly appreciated!

Comment: I do not understand the question. Is each post a hash? How is it losing fields?

Comment: What do you mean by "losing fields"? I calculate the real-time distance between a post and current_user in a helper after which I map that distance between post and user to the post-object by turning the posts into a hash. To clarify: I have figured out how to order the hash by distance – But how do I order the @sorted_posts by something else and still including the distance-number without sorting by distance?

Comment: I suspect you want something like `obj.sort_by { |e| [e.created_at, -e.vote_count, e.distance] }`. Arrays are compared with the method [Array#<=>](https://ruby-doc.org/core-2.7.0/Array.html#method-i-3C-3D-3E). See especially the third paragraph of the doc.

Comment: Just to point out that in standard timestamp implementation, `created_at` is a datetime object that stores when the object was created right down to the second.  Ordering by `created_at` and then any other field is the same as ordering by just `created_at` since you're unlikely to have two records with identical `created_at` values.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should not be doing ordering in Ruby in the first place. You will be pulling all of the records out of the database and your server will start to have serious performance problem and eventually start crashing when your app scales as it will exhaust the available memory.

Instead you want to use `.order` which adds an order clause to the query to sort the results.

```
Post.near([48.848903, 2.354533])
    .order(
       created_at: :asc, 
       vote_count: :desc
    )
```

This allows you to apply paging and limits to the query to prevent the above mentioned memory issues.

`.near` is a special scope provided by the [Geocoder gem](https://github.com/alexreisner/geocoder) which selects two special calculated geospatial columns - `distance` and `bearing`. It also orders by distance.

Here I'm using a static set of coordinates but you can pass a set of coordinates from your model or even an address that will be geocoded:

```
# to_coordinates is provided by Geocoder
Post.near(user.to_coordinates)
    .order(
       created_at: :asc, 
       vote_count: :desc
    )
```

```
Post.near("Beijing")
    .order(
       created_at: :asc, 
       vote_count: :desc
    )
```

If you want to select the distance but not use it for ordering use `.reorder` which replaces the order clause of the query:

```
Post.near(user.to_coordinates)
    .reorder(
       created_at: :asc, 
       vote_count: :desc
    )
```

Comment: If you are using postgres you can further optimize this by using the PostGIS extension which provides a much more efficient (and precise) distance calculation using specialized geospatial column types.

Comment: A word of warning; the community here loves to throw plain Ruby solutions at problems that really should be solved in the RDBMS since it's "more fun" to solve issues with creative loops or design patterns. That doesn't necessarily mean it's a good idea.

Comment: This is great. Thank you so much.

Answer (score -1):

Option 1: use a [presenter object](https://www.rubyguides.com/2019/09/rails-patterns-presenter-service/). Create a presenter for each post, have the presenter calculate the distance and store it in itself, sort your presenters instead of posts, render the presenters.

Option 2: store distances in a map from post ids to distances. When you are rendering a post, look up the corresponding distance in the post id-distance map.